# Display Sum of overdue payments in Customer Form view for each customer

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

In accounting -> Customer Invoices, there is a filter called `Overdue`. Now I want to calculate the overdue payments per user and then display it onto the customer form view.
I just want to know how can we apply the condition of **filter** in python code. I have already defined a smart button to display it with a (total invoice value) by inheriting account.invoice.

"Overdue" filter in invoice search view:

`['&', ('date_due', '<', time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), ('state', '=', 'open')]`

Comment: What do you mean by "payments per user"?

Comment: I meant sum of all overdue payments of particular user.

Comment: After adding "edited" question part to my problem. That worked for me. @CZoellner

Comment: I don't get the user part. Why should odoo users have overdue payments? Do you mean partners instead?

Comment: Yes you got it right, I meant res.partner(Customers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your smart button on partners should use a new action, like the button for customer or vendor bills. This button definition should include `context="{'default_partner_id': active_id}` which will allow to change the partner filter later on, or the upcoming action definition should include the partner in its domain.
The action should be for model `account.invoice` and have to have the following domain:
`[('date_due', '<', time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), ('state', '=', 'open')]`

If you want to filter only outgoing (customer invoices) add a filter tuple for field `type`.